# post fetch method is not working using placeholder typicode

Tags: javascript

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
    method: 'POST'
}).then(function (response) {
    // The API call was successful!
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(response);
    }
}).then(function (data) {
    // This is the JSON from our response
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function (err) {
    // There was an error
    console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
});
```

post fetch method is not working tried below code does not responding any response what could the cause please guide

Getting failed net err_failed typicode placeholder

or probably Access to fetch at 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' from origin 'https://cdpn.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: NetworkError is occurred

Answer (score 0):

Please remove completely the fetch options object

`{
    method: 'POST'
}`

from your call.

This call should be `GET` and no `POST`

Comment: Why remove this ? it is post method

Comment: Ok, since jsonplaceholder supports both GET and POST on all routes, then its a problem on their side. The request fails on postman as well. GET works normally

Comment: What problem they could have Any idea ?